# Trigonometry Challenge

Tags: trigonometry

Since I made this problem I have been trying to solve it, I know is completely defined because I use CAD software to check it, so it is doable, The problem is to find $y$, $x1$, and $x2$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\theta$ in the diagram below:

[image]

this is what I have advanced so far:

[image]

then if we have the relation of a, b, c, theta, and z, we should be able to calculate z if we are given numerical values for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\theta$ later on, so now the last part would be to find $x1$ in relation to $a$ and $x2$ in relation to $b$ which are perpendicular to the line $z$ that is equal to $2y$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best assist you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to make a bad impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: The original question (before you edited it to "find...") is better than this current version. You mentioned using CAD and numerical values and such, which will count as "effort" and attract much less close/downvotes.

Comment: sure I can show what I have but it is also a diagram

Comment: You can write $$c = \left(\sqrt{a^2-(y\cos\theta)^2}-y\sin\theta\right) + \left(\sqrt{b^2-(y\cos\theta)^2}-y\sin\theta\right)$$ Eliminating the radicals leaves a quartic in $y$. While there is a [formula for the roots of such a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), it is ugly. It's *possible* that the expressions for the roots of this specific quartic simplify in some way, but I have my doubts.

Comment: lol I can't believe I didn't see something so simple, I will try to solve for y in that formula, I will tell you if I get something good

Comment: I just saw the roots of y, and yeah as you said they are ugly, but your approach to the problem was exactly what I was looking for since you could solve the equation when you have the numeric value of a,b,c, and theta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding-upon a comment ...

[image]

$$\begin{align}
c &= ( p - y\sin\theta ) + ( q - y\sin\theta ) \\[6pt]
  &= \left( \sqrt{ a^2 - (y\cos\theta)^2 } - y\sin\theta \right) + \left( \sqrt{b^2-(y\cos\theta)^2} - y\sin\theta\right)
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

Eliminating the radicals leaves this quartic in $y$:

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 16 y^4 \sin^2\theta \\[4pt]
&+ 16 y^3 c \sin\theta (1 + \sin^2\theta ) \\[4pt]
&+ 4 y^2 (c^2 +\sin^2\theta(- 2 a^2 - 2 b^2 + 5 c^2)) \\[4pt]
&- 8 y c \sin\theta (-c^2 + a^2 + b^2)  \\[4pt]
&- (a + b + c)(-a + b + c) (a - b + c) (a + b - c)  
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

While there is [a formula for the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) of such a thing, it is ugly. It's *possible* that the expressions for the roots of this specific quartic simplify in some way, but I have my doubts.

That said, it may be worth noting that the polynomial admits a bit of a rewrite, provided that lengths $a$, $b$, $c$ form a triangle (with, say, opposite angles $A$, $B$, $C$). Then

$$\begin{align}
c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos C \tag{3} \\[4pt]
|\triangle ABC|^2 &= \frac1{16}(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) = \frac14a^2b^2\sin^2 C \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

so that $(2)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 4 y^4 \sin^2\theta \\[4pt]
&+ 4 y^3 c \sin\theta (1 + \sin^2\theta ) \\[4pt]
&+ \phantom{4}y^2 (c^2\cos^2\theta +4\sin^2\theta(c^2-a b \cos C)) \\[4pt]
&- 4 y a b c \sin\theta \cos C   \\[4pt]
&- \phantom{4}a^2b^2\sin^2 C  
\end{align} \tag{5}$$

Does this improve the polynomial's chances of having simplifiable roots? I'll leave that question to the reader.

Comment: thx, that helped a lot, I also added a bit of info and bonus in the question,